# Retrieving only latest record in iteration after adding multiple values to list using Java

Tags: java, groovy

I'm trying to add multiple records to a list and iterate. But it's displaying only latest records added.

Here is my code

```
List<ExportBean> exportBeans = new ArrayList<ExportBean>();
ExportBean exportBean = new ExportBean();
exportBean.setBooleanValue(true);
exportBean.setKeyValue("PRE_APPROVED_OFFER");
exportBean.setStringValue("111");
exportBeans.add(exportBean);
exportBean.setBooleanValue(true);
exportBean.setKeyValue("PRE_APPROVED_OFFER1");
exportBean.setStringValue("222");
exportBeans.add(exportBean);
getLopRefNo(exportBeans);
```

When I iterate it

```
def getLopRefNo = {
    exportBeans->
       println "in function ${exportBeans}"
}
```

It shows only

```
in function [ExportMessagingBean{stringValue='222', keyValue='PRE_APPROVED_OFFER1', exportBoolean=true}, ExportMessagingBean{stringValue='222', keyValue='PRE_APPROVED_OFFER1', exportBoolean=true}]
```

It doesn't show the first record added. Is it missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with Groovy. In your code, you are not actually adding two objects, you are adding one object and modifying it.

```
List<ExportBean> exportBeans = new ArrayList<ExportBean>();
ExportBean exportBean = new ExportBean();
exportBean.setBooleanValue(true);
exportBean.setKeyValue("PRE_APPROVED_OFFER");
exportBean.setStringValue("111");

exportBeans.add(exportBean); // add object to list

exportBean.setBooleanValue(true);
exportBean.setKeyValue("PRE_APPROVED_OFFER1");
exportBean.setStringValue("222");

exportBeans.add(exportBean); // this time, the same reference is "added". This does not result in an addition (in fact, "add" will return false here

getLopRefNo(exportBeans);
```

You are calling `add` with an object that is already present in the list so it has no effect. What you should do is create another instance of `ExportBean`, like this:

```
List<ExportBean> exportBeans = new ArrayList<ExportBean>();
ExportBean exportBean = new ExportBean();
exportBean.setBooleanValue(true);
exportBean.setKeyValue("PRE_APPROVED_OFFER");
exportBean.setStringValue("111");

exportBeans.add(exportBean); // add object to list

exportBean = new ExportBean(); //create new instance of ExportBean
exportBean.setBooleanValue(true);
exportBean.setKeyValue("PRE_APPROVED_OFFER1");
exportBean.setStringValue("222");

exportBeans.add(exportBean); // this new instance will be correctly added

getLopRefNo(exportBeans);
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have one `ExportBean` object in your code (you only said `new ExportBean()` once) so you have added the same object to the list twice. Your second set of calls to the `set` methods on the bean just updates your existing object rather than creating a new one.

Comment: got the fix. Thanks for ur comment

Comment: @Nizam no problem, please upvote/accept answers that were helpful